# Sending back custom JSON response with ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm trying to send back user information from the backend to the frontend but I'm having a hard time understanding how this is supposed to be formatted.

#### CONTROLLLER

```
  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)

    if user.save
      auth_token = Knock::AuthToken.new(payload: { sub: user.id })
      created_user = {
        userEmail: user.email,
        userID:    user.id
      }

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: auth_token, created_user }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: { errors: user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is in the success path. It's giving me this error when I try to run my test.

#### ERROR:

```
SyntaxError:
   /Users/Desktop/Work/ping-party/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
   /Users/Desktop/Work/ping-party/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:29: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
   /Users/Desktop/Work/ping-party/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
```

#### TEST:

```
context "POST /v1/users" do
it "create a new user" do
  post '/api/v1/users',
    params: {
      user: {
        email: "test@idea.com",
        password: "password123"
      }
    }

  res = JSON.parse(response.body)
  binding.pry
  expect(res).to include("jwt")
  expect(res).to include("user")
  expect(User.count).to eq(1)
end
end
```

It says there is a syntax error but for the life of me I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
render json: auth_token, created_user
```

The syntax is incorrect. Probably (according to your tests) you want something like:

```
render json: { user: created_user, jwt: auth_token.token)
```

[More info](https://github.com/nsarno/knock/blob/26c9090abc11b0eecc369d4c8f89f90c10f3ae33/app/model/knock/auth_token.rb#L28).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm getting this error when I try this: NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to_h' for #<Knock::AuthToken:0x007fe79b2f2a80>
       Did you mean?  to_s

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @mudasobwa

Comment: Please check the update. I never worked with `knock` library and I thought you might figure out yourself how to get a jwt out of `AuthToken` instance. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can store auth_token and created_user in a hash:

```
auth_token = Knock::AuthToken.new(payload: { sub: user.id })
created_user = {
  userEmail: user.email,
  userID:    user.id
}
output = { auth_token: auth_token, created_user: created_user }
```

...

```
format.json { render json: output }
```

Then rails can render output like json.

Comment: Tests clearly tell that the response is expected to have keys `"user"` and `"jwt"`.